# C I would like to tokenize a string by delimiter except within quotes

Tags: c, token, delimiter

I would like to tokenize both quoted and unquoted strings. I have found solutions in java, python or c++. Any idea how to do this in C?

```
string = "ADD, "IMM, REG", 8"
tokens = {"ADD", "IMM, REG", "8"}
```

Comment: use [`strtok`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

Comment: First: `"ADD, "IMM, REG", 8"` is not a string. You should escape the quotes to put them inside a literal string. Second: where did the `,` afther the `ADD` go? My hint is: search for the quotes and treat the separately, then use `strtok` to separate the others.

Comment: How does the string `"ADD, PLAIN\",QUOTE,\"TEXT, 8"` get tokenized?  Is the second token `"PLAIN\",QUOTE,\"TEXT"`?  If not, what is it?  The significance of this Is whether the embedded quotes must appear at the start and end of a nested string, as more or less happens in the example in the question, or whether they can appear at arbitrary positions in a field.  What should happen if the string contains an odd number of double quotes?

Comment: FWIW: I don't think there's a standard C function that directly supports this form of tokenization, regardless of the answer to my question about obscure patterns of quoting text.

Comment: You might like to learn about "regular expressions." There is no standard C library, though. But you will find some commonly used library on your web recherche.